# Migrating from windows to linux deployment for NET 6 app with angular (IIS to nginx as a reverse proxy)

Tags: c#, angular, linux, nginx, .net-core

I've developed and deployed a NET 6 app with angular and I've hosted it to Windows 2019 server with IIS. So far so good, the app works and everything is fine. Recently I've been asked to deploy it on a linux server (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). I'm facing an issue, which I've been stuck to it for a about a week, looked here and in various sources to be able to make it to work but with no luck. My thought goes that there is something wrong with the IdentityServer nuget and the appsettings.json file.

below is the startup.cs file of my app

```
//using statements....

namespace AppNameSpace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        private IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
                    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                    {
                        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                    }));

            services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                    {
                        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                    }));

            //add repositories here....           

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddIdempotentAPIUsingDistributedCache();

            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                
            }).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.Developer.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role,             AuthorizationEnum.Claims.developer.ToString()));

                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.Easymint.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.easymint.ToString()));

                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.Administrator.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.administrator.ToString()));

                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.Manager.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.manager.ToString()));

                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.Tester.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.tester.ToString()));

                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.User.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.user.ToString()));
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddMvc();

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            services.AddScoped<LoggingActionFilter>();

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));

            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders =
                    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            });

            services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero; // This ensures that the security stamp is validated on every request
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.AddCors();

            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("<server static IP>"));
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseXContentTypeOptions();
            app.UseReferrerPolicy(r => r.StrictOriginWhenCrossOrigin());
            app.UseXDownloadOptions();
            app.UseXRobotsTag(r => r
                .NoFollow()
                .NoIndex());
            app.UseXXssProtection(x => x.Enabled());

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();


            app.UseCsp(options => options
                .FrameAncestors(f => f.Self()));

            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();            
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{operation}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    //comment the line below before deployment
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and the program.cs file is the following

````
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true).Build();

                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                    .CreateLogger();

                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel().UseUrls("http://*:5000");
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                    .UseSerilog();
    }
}```
````

now, the above works fine when deployed on IIS on windows...
Below I have the service file on linux

```
[Unit]
Description=Description

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/appFolder/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/appFolder/appName.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=AppName
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://<server-IP>:5000

TimeoutStopSec=90

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip off;

application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include nginx-app.conf;
}
```

the included file

```
server {        
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 http2;

        ssl_certificate /var/ssl/local.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/ssl/local.decrypted.key;
        server_name easymint.local.com;

        root /var/www/appfolder/;
        index index.html;
        autoindex off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<server IP>:5000;
    
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

and of course the sites available file which has a symbolic link to sites enabled

```
server {
    #listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/appfolder;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name easymint.local.com;

    location / {
                proxy_pass http://<server-IP>:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep_alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

last but not least there is the appsettings.json file

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "<conn-str-values>"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "/var/ssl/<fqdn_cert_name>.pfx",
      "Password": "<password>"
    },
    "Clients": {
      "EasyMint": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

The service and nginx work fine as a serice and reverse proxy respectively.
But when I open the web page from the browser. I get an authorization failed error and the app does not redirect to the login form.

Could you please help me pinpoint the issue ? should I check on the angular side (frontend) as well ? or is it just a backend issue ? Has enyone enountered this before ?

The browser console states that the app could not load the settings, from the "_configuration" endpoint, from which I can tell, is autogenerated in the VS net app with angular template.

Please let me know if I've missed any vital information regarding the matter, as I'm really frustrated

Thank you in advance

Differnt configurations, possuble solutions on github and stack overflow and official documentation from microsoft

I was expecrting to be able to navigate to the login screen and log into the application.